# Cloudinary destroy method not working in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, cloudinary

I'm currently building an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC for my course. I'm using Cloudinary for storing files in the cloud so I can get bonus points, but I have a problem with deleting files from it. In the documentation is written that I should use DeletionParams class and pass the publicId which I'm storing in the database, but whatever I do the DeletionParams class is returning me "not found".

```
public void DeleteFile(string publicId)
        {
            var deletionParams = new DeletionParams(publicId)
            {
                ResourceType = ResourceType.Raw
            };

            var results = cloudinary.Destroy(deletionParams);
            ;
        }
```

[And this is what parameters I pass to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRatd.png)

[And this is the result from cloudinary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldESe.png)

If more information is needed just ask in the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the problem. When you want to delete an image you should provide folder and `publidId` and also `ResourceType = ResourceType.Image`. If you want to delete a video it's the same way the only thing you should change is ResourceType to `ResourceType.Video`. For any kinds of other files you should provide *full path plus public id and also the file extension* and ResoureType should be `ResourceType.Raw`

Comment: Just adding, that in Cloudinary, the public ID consists of the asset's folder path concatenated with its filename (for non-image and non-video resources, aka `raw`, this also includes the file extension). E.g if an image resides under the `folder/sub-folder/my-image` Cloudinary path, then that's its public ID.